# Dealing with readLines() function in R

Tags: r, readlines

I'm experiencing a very hard time with R lately.

I'm not an expert user but I'm trying to use R to read a plain text (`.txt`) file and capture each line of it. After that, I want to deal with those lines and make some breaks and changes in the text.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
fileName <- "C:/MyFolder/TEXT_TO_BE_PROCESSED.txt"
con <- file(fileName,open="r")
line <- readLines(con)
close(con)
```

It reads the text and the line breaks perfectly. But I don't understand how the created object `line` works.

The object `line` created with this code has the class: `character` and the length `[57]`.
If I type `line[1]` it shows exactly the text of the first line. But if I type

```
length(line[1])
```

it returns me `[1]`.

I would like to know how can I transform this string of `length == 1` that contains 518 in fact into a string of `length == 518`.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I don't need to necessarily use the `readLines()` function. I've did some research and also found the function `scan()`, but I ended with the same situation of a immutable string of 518 characters but `length == 1`.

Hope I've been clear enough about my doubt. Sorry for the bad English.

Comment: `readLines` returns "A character vector of length the number of lines read." (from `?readLines`). That's why each line is length 1.  Have you tried `read.csv` or `read.table` for this?

Comment: Please provide some of the data and what you expect as a result.  It sounds like you just need `strsplit`

Comment: Try `nchar(line[1])`, it'll give you the number of characters in the first element of list (i.e., the first line of your file). `length(list)` tells you the number of lines retrieved from the file; by giving it `length(list[1])`, you're asking it the number of elements in a slice of list, a slice that happens to have a single element in it (which may be a string of length 518 or whatever).

Comment: @r2evans The `nchar(line[1])` returns me the number os characters on the string. But I wannna know how to access those characters individually. The `strsplit` function does not satisfy my needs. The best way to describe what I wanna do is to say that I want to read every line of `line` (i.e.: `line[1]`, `line[2]`, ... , `line[n]`) character by character (blank or not) and make some rearrangements.

Comment: Without a better idea of what exactly you want to break a string into, my guidance is merely `?substr` and `?regexp`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose `txt` is the text from line 1 of your data that you read in with `readLines`.
Then if you want to split it into separate strings, each of which is a word, then you can use `strsplit`, splitting at the space between each word.

```
> txt <- paste0(letters[1:10], LETTERS[1:10], collapse = " ")
> txt
## [1] "aA bB cC dD eE fF gG hH iI jJ"   ## character vector of length 1
> length(txt)
[1] 1
> newTxt <- unlist(strsplit(txt, split = "\\s"))  ## split the string at the spaces
> newTxt
## [1] "aA" "bB" "cC" "dD" "eE" "fF" "gG" "hH" "iI" "jJ"
## now the text is a character vector of length 10  
> length(newTxt)
[1] 10
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is not exactly what I need. I dont want do split the vector in words. For me the blank spaces are really important and i want each blank space to count as a character too. The final product I'm looking for, in your example, would be a string of 29 characters.

Comment: Okay, then instead of `split = "\\s"`, use `split = ""`

Comment: The solution suggested by @Richard Scriven solved my problem. I'm really grateful. Changing the split argument was what I needed to get it done.

Answer (score 5):

You can firstly condense that code into a single line, the other 3 lines just make objects that you don't need.

```
line <- readLines("C:/MyFolder/TEXT_TO_BE_PROCESSED.txt")
```

The if you want to know how many space separated words per line

```
words <- sapply(line,function(x) length(unlist(strsplit(x,split=" "))))
```

If you leave out the `length` argument in the above you get a list of character vectors of the words from each line.

Comment: I've tried this solutions. Leaving out the length argument it returns me a variable "words" that is a list of 57. If I type words[1]. It returns me the whole first line splited word by word. But I can't access a specific words like I want example.: words[1][2].

Comment: then you need to look up the difference between `[` and `[[`. To get the first word of the first list entry you want `words[[1]][1]`

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
con <- file(fileName, open='r')
text <- readLines(con)[[1]]
```

to get the text of the first line of the file.