# R language/reporteRs loop to write multiple docx

Tags: r, docx

I'm trying (as hard as i can) to create a script that will generate formatted word documents from plain text files using R language and reporteRs.

To extract text from one txt i'm using this code found on this thread [Dealing with readLines() function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001548/dealing-with-readlines-function-in-r/23003050#23003050) :

```
fileName <- "C:/MyFolder/TEXT_TO_BE_PROCESSED.txt"
con <- file(fileName,open="r")
line <- readLines(con)
close(con)
```

Then add the extracted text to docx with this :

```
doc <- docx(template="temp.docx")
```

Next, adding the title (first line of the txt file)

```
doc <- addParagraph( doc, value = line[1], bookmark = "titre", stylename = "Titre")
```

then the body of the txt file

```
doc <- addParagraph( doc, value = line[2:length(line)], value = line[2:55], stylename = "Contenu")
```

Finally I create the docx

```
writeDoc(doc, file = "output-file.docx")
```

I want to be able to create a loop so I can generate multiple docx from multiple txt files. I will really appreciate your help

Comment: `line[2:length(line)]` will extract everything from the second line to the end. You need to use something like `lapply` with a vector of filenames to get a loop working

Comment: Thank you for your reply Richard, I edited the code in the post relative to extracting txt to the end. I'm not sure to know how to use `lapply` but I'll try to look in the documentation. Can you help if you know ?

Comment: HELP NEEDED !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this with `lapply`

```
myFiles <- c("C:/MyFolder/TEXT_TO_BE_PROCESSED.txt", "C:/MyFolder/TEXT_TO_BE_PROCESSED2.txt") # or use list.files()

lapply(myFiles, function(fileName){
  con <- file(fileName,open="r")
  line <- readLines(con) # you could just call readLines(fileName)
  close(con)
  doc <- docx(template="temp.docx")
  doc <- addParagraph( doc, value = line[1], bookmark = "titre", stylename = "Titre")
  doc <- addParagraph( doc, value = line[2:length(line)], value = line[2:55], stylename = "Contenu")
  writeDoc(doc, file = paste0(fileName, "out.docx"))
})
```

Comment: This is working as a charm ! Thank you sir, so much.

Comment: I added a missing ")" at the end of writeDoc line. Should i edit my post now ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution :

```
myFiles <- list.files()

lapply(myFiles, function(fileName){
line <- readLines(fileName)
doc <- docx(template="temp.docx")
doc <- addParagraph( doc, value = line[1], bookmark = "titre", 
stylename = "Titre »)
doc <- addParagraph( doc, value = line[2:length(line)], stylename = "Contenu")
writeDoc(doc, file = paste0(fileName, ".docx"))
})
```

Thank you again Richard