# How to convert the output from readLines into a dataframe

Tags: r, function, csv, data.table, bigdata

I am attempting to use `readLines` to import a 17.6GB csv file into R. I have tried several approaches discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38536226/r-reading-a-huge-csv/38536279), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45594639/how-do-i-import-a-large-6-gb-csv-file-into-r-efficiently-and-quickly-without), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527587/select-specified-rows-when-importing-csv), and elsewhere and `readLines` seems to be the only approach that effectively at least can get the data into R.

The problem is that I am unable to convert the output from `readLines` into a data frame which I can use in my analysis. The answers to a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001548/dealing-with-readlines-function-in-r) are not helping me solve my problem.

**Here is my sample data:**

```
write.csv(data.frame(myid=1:10,var=runif(10)),"temp.csv")

dt<-data.frame(myid=1:10,var=runif(10))
dt

myid       var
1     1 0.5949020
2     2 0.8515591
3     3 0.8139010
4     4 0.3804234
5     5 0.4923082
6     6 0.9933775
7     7 0.1740895
8     8 0.8342808
9     9 0.3958154
10   10 0.9690561
```

**creating chunks:**

```
file_i <- file("temp.csv","r")
chunk_size <- 100000 # choose the best size for you
x<- readLines(file_in, n=chunk_size)
```

**Opening the output from readLines in R:**

```
View(x)
x
 [1] "\"\",\"myid\",\"var\""      
 [2] "\"1\",1,0.594902001088485"  
 [3] "\"2\",2,0.851559089729562"  
 [4] "\"3\",3,0.81390100880526"   
 [5] "\"4\",4,0.380423351423815"  
 [6] "\"5\",5,0.492308202432469"  
 [7] "\"6\",6,0.993377464590594"  
 [8] "\"7\",7,0.174089450156316"  
 [9] "\"8\",8,0.834280799608678"  
[10] "\"9\",9,0.395815373631194"  
[11] "\"10\",10,0.969056134112179"
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I have >50,000,000 rows. Is it possible to have a function that implements your suggested idea and then merges the resulting chunks by row? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried `data.table::fread`?

Comment: Yes. I have tried `data.table::fread`. No success. Also, have tried: `bigmemory::read.big.matrix`, and `sqldf::read.csv.sql`. All of them return: `Error: cannot allocate vector of size XX Mb`.

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: Please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb

Comment: I have 16GB of RAM.

Comment: I would go for some command line pre-processing like `sed` or `awk` to clean up input, then fread.

Comment: instead of `View(x)` use `head tmp.csv` from command line so we have clear picture what the csv is like, and not how it is interpreted by R function `View`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complete sequence of instructions to transform the data as you posted into a dataframe.

```
set.seed(1234)    # Make the results reproducible

write.csv(data.frame(myid=1:10,var=runif(10)),"temp.csv")

dat <- readLines("temp.csv")
df1 <- strsplit(dat[-1], ",")
df1 <- do.call(rbind, df1)
df1 <- df1[,-1]
df1 <- as.data.frame(df1)
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))

names(df1) <- gsub('"', '', strsplit(dat[1], ',')[[1]][-1], fixed = TRUE)
df1
```

Comment: I'm frankly amazed this works and `fread` does not. What version of `data.table` are you using?

Comment: `do.call` `rbind` will be very slow for so many rows, better to switch to `data.table::rbindlist` here

Answer (score 0):

Given the output you get after readLines, this must be the content of your CSV file:

```
"","myid","var"
"1","1","0.5949020"
"2","2","0.8515591"
"3","3","0.8139010"
"4","4","0.3804234"
"5","5","0.4923082"
"6","6","0.9933775"
"7","7","0.1740895"
"8","8","0.8342808"
"9","9","0.3958154"
"10","10","0.9690561"
```

That is, **your values are *comma separated* and *enclosed in double quotes***. When I read in this file, I get your output:

```
dat
 [1] "\"\",\"myid\",\"var\""       "\"1\",\"1\",\"0.5949020\""  
 [3] "\"2\",\"2\",\"0.8515591\""   "\"3\",\"3\",\"0.8139010\""  
 [5] "\"4\",\"4\",\"0.3804234\""   "\"5\",\"5\",\"0.4923082\""  
 [7] "\"6\",\"6\",\"0.9933775\""   "\"7\",\"7\",\"0.1740895\""  
 [9] "\"8\",\"8\",\"0.8342808\""   "\"9\",\"9\",\"0.3958154\""  
[11] "\"10\",\"10\",\"0.9690561\""
```

So what you need to do is

- **split at the commas**
  with `unlist(strsplit(..., split = ",")`

and

- **replace the escaped double quotes**
  with `gsub("\"", "", ...)`

which gives us:

```
unlist(strsplit(gsub("\"", "", dat), split = ","))

 [1] ""          "myid"      "var"       "1"         "1"         "0.5949020" "2"        
 [8] "2"         "0.8515591" "3"         "3"         "0.8139010" "4"         "4"        
[15] "0.3804234" "5"         "5"         "0.4923082" "6"         "6"         "0.9933775"
[22] "7"         "7"         "0.1740895" "8"         "8"         "0.8342808" "9"        
[29] "9"         "0.3958154" "10"        "10"        "0.9690561"
```

Comment: When I do: `unlist(strsplit(x, split = "\\s"))` I get:
 `[1] "\"\",\"myid\",\"var\""      
 [2] "\"1\",1,0.188206466846168"  
 [3] "\"2\",2,0.749221669742838"  
 [4] "\"3\",3,0.308469610055909"  
 [5] "\"4\",4,0.379058901453391"  
 [6] "\"5\",5,0.750765843084082"  
 [7] "\"6\",6,0.70420167548582"   
 [8] "\"7\",7,0.920593033544719"  
 [9] "\"8\",8,0.795277312630787"  
[10] "\"9\",9,0.829076963244006"  
[11] "\"10\",10,0.167547662509605"`, which is not the desired output.

Comment: The desired output is: `myid       var
1     1 0.5949020
2     2 0.8515591
3     3 0.8139010
4     4 0.3804234
5     5 0.4923082
6     6 0.9933775
7     7 0.1740895
8     8 0.8342808
9     9 0.3958154
10   10 0.9690561`

Comment: Don't `unlist`. Run `do.call(rbind, unlist(strsplit(dat, split = "\\s"))`.

Comment: When I do: `do.call(rbind, unlist(strsplit(x, split = "\\s")))` I get: `Error in do.call(rbind, unlist(strsplit(x, split = "\\s"))) : 
  second argument must be a list`.